# Combining Row Info in DataBase

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm currently working on a query that I need to combine some info for

Below is the query that I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.SiteID,
    s.GroupID,
    sa.StartDateTime,
    u.UserFirstName + SPACE(1) + UserLastName ScanName,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,sa.StartDateTime,101) ApptStartDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,sa.EndDateTime,101) ApptEndDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS TIME),100) ApptStartTime,
    saa.Time ArrivalTime,
    sl.Address,
    st.StateShortCode,
    ct.CityName,
    CASE saa.CheckInCallType 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Inbound' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Outbound' END AS CallCheckInType,
    CASE WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 1 THEN 'Arrived' 
        WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 2 THEN 'No Show'
        WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 3 THEN 'Reschedule'
        WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 4 THEN 'Provider Reschedule'
        WHEN sa.SiteAppointmentStatusID=998 THEN 'Cancelled'
        ELSE 'Pending' END AS CheckInStatus,
    ISNULL(saa.CheckInComments,'') CheckInComments,
    um.ManagerName,
    u.UserPhone,
    u.UserCell,
    u.UserAddress,
    ci.CityName as ScannerCityName,
    st.StateShortCode as ScannerState
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointments sa ON s.SiteID = sa.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentsScanners sas ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = sas.SiteAppointmentID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON sas.ScannerUserID = u.UserID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteLocation sl ON sa.SiteID = sl.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.States st ON sl.StateID = st.StateID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cities ct ON sl.CityID = ct.CityID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentArrivals saa ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = saa.SiteAppointmentId 
                                              AND saa.ScannerUserID = sas.ScannerUserID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserManagers um ON u.UserManagerID=um.ManagerID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Cities ci ON u.CityID=ci.CityID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.States st2 ON st2.StateID=u.StateID
WHERE 
    ProjectID = 110
    AND 
        (
            (CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
            OR
            (CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
        )
    AND ((CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014') OR saa.Date IS NULL)
```

The info is all good but I want to combine some of the row info into one block of info.

Here is an example:

**Ex.1**

```
Site ID | Group ID | StateDateTime            | ScanName | ApptStartDate | ApptEndDate | ApptStartTime | ArrivalTime             | Address | StateShortCode | CityName | CallCheckInType | CheckInComments | Manager Name | UserPhone | UserCell | UserAddress | ScannerCityName | Scanner State
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345   | 67890    | 2014-09-03 09:30:00.000  | Jane Doe | 09/03/2014    | 09/03/2014  | 9:30AM        | 2014-09-03 09:13:01.507 | 123 St  | NY             | New York | Inbound         |                 | Manager1     | 1234567   |          | 321 St      | New York        | NY 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54321   | 67890    | 2014-09-03 09:30:00.000  | Jane Doe | 09/03/2014    | 09/03/2014  | 9:30AM        | 2014-09-03 09:13:01.507 | 123 St  | NY             | New York | Inbound         |                 | Manager1     | 1234567   |          | 321 St      | New York        | NY
```

GroupIDs show that a lot of SiteIDs (which all have unique numbers) are actually grouped together into one GroupID.  I would like to combine these rows into one row (rather than multiple rows with multiple SiteIDs showing) that displays just one SiteID (doesn't matter which one)

I also get instances like this as well

**Ex.2**

```
Site ID | Group ID | StateDateTime            | ScanName | ApptStartDate | ApptEndDate | ApptStartTime | ArrivalTime             | Address | StateShortCode | CityName | CallCheckInType | CheckInComments | Manager Name | UserPhone | UserCell | UserAddress | ScannerCityName | Scanner State
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
09876   | 24680    | 2014-09-03 08:00:00.000  | John Doe | 09/03/2014    | 09/03/2014  | 8:00AM        | NULL                    | 123 St  | NY             | New York | Pending         |                 | Manager1     | 1234567   |          | 321 St      | New York        | NY 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
09877   | 24680    | 2014-09-03 08:00:00.000  | John Doe | 09/03/2014    | 09/03/2014  | 8:00AM        | 2014-09-03 09:09:48.053 | 123 St  | NY             | New York | Inbound         |                 | Manager1     | 1234567   |          | 321 St      | New York        | NY
```

Where the user who arrives at the appointment but does not sign into all the sites within the group (so I get a null value for the Arrival Time) - however, if the user signs up to even one site within the group they should still seen as being arrived within the entire group.  In this case I would also like to "combine" - or remove the Null cases here but keep the non-null value (in this example there is only one Site that has a date but it could be multiple sites within the group that could be signed in but a few stranglers that are null). I know having a `JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN` would help the issue.  However, I still want to get NULL values for instances were the person does not show up as all in any of the sites within a group.

Answer (score 0):

** Updated based on comment **

The absolute cheapest way to do this would be the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    max(s.SiteID),
    s.GroupID,
    sa.StartDateTime,
    u.UserFirstName + SPACE(1) + UserLastName ScanName,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,sa.StartDateTime,101) ApptStartDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,sa.EndDateTime,101) ApptEndDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS TIME),100) ApptStartTime,
    saa.Time ArrivalTime,
    sl.Address,
    st.StateShortCode,
    ct.CityName,
    CASE saa.CheckInCallType 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Inbound' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Outbound' END AS CallCheckInType,
    CASE WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 1 THEN 'Arrived' 
        WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 2 THEN 'No Show'
        WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 3 THEN 'Reschedule'
        WHEN saa.CheckInStatus = 4 THEN 'Provider Reschedule'
        WHEN sa.SiteAppointmentStatusID=998 THEN 'Cancelled'
        ELSE 'Pending' END AS CheckInStatus,
    ISNULL(saa.CheckInComments,'') CheckInComments,
    um.ManagerName,
    u.UserPhone,
    u.UserCell,
    u.UserAddress,
    ci.CityName as ScannerCityName,
    st.StateShortCode as ScannerState
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointments sa ON s.SiteID = sa.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentsScanners sas ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = sas.SiteAppointmentID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON sas.ScannerUserID = u.UserID
    INNER JOIN dbo.SiteLocation sl ON sa.SiteID = sl.SiteID
    INNER JOIN dbo.States st ON sl.StateID = st.StateID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Cities ct ON sl.CityID = ct.CityID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteAppointmentArrivals saa ON sa.SiteAppointmentID = saa.SiteAppointmentId 
                                              AND saa.ScannerUserID = sas.ScannerUserID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.UserManagers um ON u.UserManagerID=um.ManagerID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Cities ci ON u.CityID=ci.CityID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.States st2 ON st2.StateID=u.StateID
WHERE 
    ProjectID = 110
    AND 
        (
            (CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.StartDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
            OR
            (CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(sa.EndDateTime AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014')
        )
    AND ((CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) >= '09/03/2014' AND CAST(saa.Date AS DATE) <= '09/03/2014') OR saa.Date IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18, 19 -- short hand for grouping columns together, because there are 20 columns, and only the first one is excluded;
```

Comment: Hmm perhaps combine wasn't a good word - I don't necessarily want to combine the info from both rows - I kind of just want to pluck one set of info (since all the info is the same minus the SiteID) - and in the case of the Null and No Null - I want one selected not null value

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just a couple of questions - where are the numbers in the GroupBy coming from? In addition - I'm also getting the error "Each Group By expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"

Comment: Actually just replaced the numbers with the actual Select names and that fixed my first issue but I'm still getting that other error where the NULLs appear (example 2)

Comment: You can use numbers instead of select names for shorthand - tends to be much easier for super complex situations like this. Not sure what the NULL issue is, can you explain further?

Comment: Sure no problem - in the group there are multiple SiteIDs associated with one Group - at times - one person can arrive at one Site within the Group, and technically, all the sites with in the group would be marked as Arrvied with all the same info.  However, due to a glitch (that we're trying to fix) it'll show only that particular site as being Arrived while the others will be marked as NULL.  I would like to capture just the Arrival info and not the other NULL info (IF a user did Arrive - if they didn't arrive for any sites within a group then an row with a NULL value in ArrivalTime is OK)

Comment: Which is why I can't remedy the issue with INNER JOIN (since I'm currently using LEFT JOIN) because I still want to capture the users that are No Shows (ie didn't Arrive to any Sites within the Group)

Comment: I'm thinking a CASE statement might work here? I'm just not sure how I would write that? If GroupIDs are multiple and one of them has an ArrivalTime then display that row - else just display one null row.

Comment: Quick question - why'd you use the two different structures for CheckInStatus? I.E.:

    CASE saa.CheckInStatus
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Arrived' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'No Show'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Reschedule'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Provider Reschedule'
        WHEN sa.SiteAppointmentStatusID = 998 THEN 'Cancelled'
        ELSE 'Pending' END AS CheckInStatus,

Comment: I would remove that column from the group by, and put MAX() on it. That sets the result for that column to be any-non-null result, or null if they're all null.

Comment: The reason for the break with that case for CheckInStatus is because there isn't a "cancelled" with the SAA table (which is SiteAppointmentArrivals) it takes place within the SA tabl (SiteAppointments) - which logically makes sense since you can't have an arrival for site with an appointment that is cancelled.

Comment: I kind of wanted to consolidate the Cancelled with the CheckInStatus (rather than have it's own section) unless you think this is unwise and would be better if it's separated?

Comment: You run the risk of both having a CheckInStatus with a valid value AND it being cancelled (through corruption/etc). Why not update, in whatever place you set 'SiteAppointmentStatusID' to ALSO set CheckInStatus to 5, and then only access the one field. The rest of the answer still holds.